# Custom UIGestureRecognizer conflicting with UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

So I have this project that I took from somebody else and they have implemented this `OneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer` (https://github.com/melle/OneFingerRotationGestureDemo/blob/master/OneFingerRotationGestureDemo/OneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer.m) for a circular slider. Additionally, they have added a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on top of that, so you could tap a value within that circular slider and the value would jump to that specific one. Now the problem is, when I drag that thing just a very small amount (imagine putting your thumb onto the control and tilting left/right), then the `UITapGestureRecognizer` also fires! And this is a problem, because I want to be able to grab the circular slider wherever I want (there is no handle or something). And when I only drag it a little, then the value just jumps to that spot where I did that small dragging. Somehow I need to cancel that tap gesture as soon as that `OneFingerRotationGestureRecognizer` started registering touches. I tried what is described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another?language=objc but didn't have any success with that :-(.

What can I do? I'm afraid the solution is so simple that I just don't see it.

Comment: Check out the [`require(toFail:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer/1624203-require) method.

Comment: @floschliep I did that, but I was unable to find a solution that works